# C++ local libraries and relative path

Tags: c++, c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have so many includes like this in my application

```
#include "../../libs/helper.hpp"
```

I am glad to remove there `../../libs/` from every include. Is there any way to fix this problem so I can call the library this way?

```
#include "helper.hpp"
```

one possible way is to use `-I` switch in make file. But the problem is that then I should use angular brackets `<` and `>` for calling libraries. It is undesirable since I prefer to distinguish between my local libraries and the installed libraries. So I am looking for a way to call it with `"` around the name of the libraries.

Is there any way?

Comment: Do you really have to use angular brackets if you use `-I`? I don't think you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -iquote*dir*
>       Add the directory *dir* to the head of the list of directories to be searched for header files only for the case of `#include "file"`; they are not searched for `#include <file>`, otherwise just like `-I`.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options